# Redirect after login using JWT authentication

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

Im using this library [django-rest-framework-simplejwt](https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt) and want to 
I want to be able to redirect to the endpoint after successfully obtaining a token.

I have a standard implementation of getting a token taken from the documentation

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt import views as jwt_views
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/token/', jwt_views.TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', jwt_views.TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
]
```

Is there any way to change the operation of the `TokenObtainPairView` function to redirect to the endpoint?

Comment: You're making a network request to obtain a token, I guess you're on client-side ( browser) in that case all you have to do is replace the window location using javascript. Or am I missing something that you didn't tell us your full use case?

Comment: I was just trying to understand to myself whether it's necessary to do that logic on the backend. Or is it normal practice to redirect on the frontend, for example, after successfully obtaining a token?

Comment: You don't have to change any logic in the backend. Think request is like a single way once it's reached the destination it will return to original place.